# floating point normalised value of -1

Tags: floating-point, number-formats

I have, lets say, 8 bits mantissa and 4 bit exponent. Then,

`-1=1111 1111`
there are no 0s so how can I normalise -1 in 2's complement form?

Comment: Sorry, I found out the answer myself. It is `1000 000` manitssa and `0000` exponent.
for mantissa, `1.000 0000 = -128 *power(2,-7)`.

for exponent, `0000 = 0`.
So, `result= -128 * power(2,-7) = -1 `.

Comment: This might seem a bit strange but can you write that as an answer instead of as a comment? That way, the question won't sit on our "unanswered" list forever.  Thanks and welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found out the answer myself. It is `1000 000` manitssa and `0000` exponent.
for mantissa, `1.000 0000 = -128 *power(2,-7)`.

for exponent, `0000 = 0`.
So, result= -128 * power(2,-7)